# Linux 16.04 LTS: Cannot upgrade PHP version manually

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, upgrade

#### Having trouble upgrading to PHP version 7.4 from 7.0.33 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version

So far, I am running `PHP 7.0.33` on my `Ubuntu 16.04` PC. Today I am trying (for the first time) to manually upgrade the PHP version to at least **7.4**, if not to 8.x.

For this I am following https://tehnoblog.org/ubuntu-tutorial-how-to-manually-upgrade-php-version/.

The following commands had completed successfully:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

But when I try to actually install the PHP version the following error is coming uo!

```
admin@linuxpc:~$ sudo apt install -y php7.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
```

Here is the output of `$ cat /etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

I am doing this upgrade process for the first time. So don't have much idea about the reason which is causing this. Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) is too old.
Ondrej PPA only supports the following operating systems (as of 10 June 2021):
Hirsute (21.04), Groovy (20.10), Focal (20.04), Bionic (18.04).

Which is why there is no package found.

The best long-term solution is to update your Ubuntu to the
latest version.

You can force this for now by adding this 3rd party repository to
your system with these two commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jczaplicki/xenial-php74-temp
sudo apt-get update
```

Note that this might work for installing php, but there is no guarantee
for the future (it does say "temp" in the repository name).
It would be better to compile it yourself if you really need to have it
installed on 16.04.

I repeat that a long-term solution is to update your system.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. Please also tell me that if I opt for the temporary solution for now, will  I be able to install / update the PHP libraries like CLI, MySqli etc. as well?

Comment: Yes, if they are included in this repository.